# Expires in, jwt token expires in moblie app

Tags: flutter, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I use in my app `accessToken` and `refreshToken`. I have implemented my token solution like below:

```
  +--------+                                           +---------------+
  |        |--(A)------- Authorization Grant --------->|               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |<-(B)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
  |        |               & Refresh Token             |               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |                            +----------+   |               |
  |        |--(C)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
  |        |                            |          |   |               |
  |        |<-(D)- Protected Resource --| Resource |   | Authorization |
  | Client |                            |  Server  |   |     Server    |
  |        |--(E)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
  |        |                            |          |   |               |
  |        |<-(F)- Invalid Token Error -|          |   |               |
  |        |                            +----------+   |               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |--(G)----------- Refresh Token ----------->|               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |<-(H)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
  +--------+           & Optional Refresh Token        +---------------+
```

My token looks like:

```
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiI....",
"refreshToken": "91792ee6-5cf4-45e6-96a5-4e5c47f4a601-188318b9-1591-41d7-9ba2-3d1b11f68383",
"expiresAt": "2022-08-23T09:40:24Z"
```

as you can see I have `expiresAt`. I check if `accessToken` expired in client side so everything works fine if `DateTime` in my device is a same as server, if time is over, application throws Session expired exception. But I have noted that if my emulator has a few minutes before actual time (I mean current time is 14:00, emulator shows 13:30, and lets token expiresAt: 13:50 and `refreshToken` is expired at 13:51) and I try post to server than server return 401 error because my client validate `accessToken` for this way: time 13:30 is before 13:50 => return true (token is alive) but server validate it as isn't alive and return status code 401. I only check `refreshToken` (on server side) when `accessToken` expired but this way when I change time on device `accessToken` will never be exipred. How to fix this situation? I know I could use `expiresIn` instead of `expiresAt` but how to implement this?

Comment: if you dont want to implement an expiresIn property, you can either use a retry mechanism, so that if you get a 401, you retry to get a new token or the other option would be to expose the server time, so that you can calculate the timespan of expiration from the client side. quick question are you using identity server?

Comment: Generally I use asp.net core and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity for authorization.

Comment: @fattikus I think your idea will be good for me, when server response 401 I try to generate new `refreshToken` and if it expired than client show 'session expired'

Comment: Other than `mobile app` is it functioning well? I mean for `web app` or any other platforms you are using that token?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I use only in moblie app.

Comment: So this token is been generated on `mobile app` no `API` or backed has not generated the token right?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron token is generated by backend when user submit login, backend return token as I write above. After that if I want to post something to backend or get, client check is token doesnt expired if expired than client send request to server to try get new accessToken by refreshToken. Backend check is refreshToken (this token is save in db) alive if true => generate new accessToken with new expiresAt, if false => throw SecurityTokenExpiredException

Comment: Thanks for the details. Need to investigate further, based on the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly...

You cannot rely on the device clock for that.

Use access token to try and fetch the resources you want, if you get a 401, try to refresh the token with the server. If that fails because it expired, then do the authorization flow again.